# Zend Framework Ajax Link to work with jQuery Dialog Box

Tags: jquery-ui, zend-framework

I have tried now the last 3 weeks to get a ajaxLink to work with a jQuery Dialog Box. I have a delete Bookmark Function and want that a dialog Box appears, where you have to confirm that you want to delete the Bookmark, before the Ajax Request is fired and deletes the Bookmark.

I assume that I have to add something to the beforeSend function, but I can not figure out what needs to be written in it. Could someone advice what I need to do? I hope someone knows the answer, I run out of ideas. Thank you very much in advance !

Here my sourcecode so far:

```
 echo $this->ajaxLink("Remove Bookmark","/bookmark/remove/article  ".$this->escape($entry->id),
               array(
                    'id' => '',
                    'class' => 'btn orange delete dialog-confirm',
                    'dataType'=>'JSON', 
                    'method' => 'post',
                    'update' => '.bookmark',
                    'beforeSend' => '????',
                    'complete' => '$("."+data+"").remove();if ($(".watchlist").length == 0){$(".watch").append("<p>No items watched</p>")}'
           ));
```

And my jQuery Dialog Box:

```
$('.dialog-confirm').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var URL = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).css('display','block');

    $('#dialogbox').dialog({

        resizable: false,
        height:180,
        width:350,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: true, 
        buttons: {
            "Yes, delete bookmark": function() {
              window.location.href = URL;
              return true;
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }

        });   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Ajax request must be triggered only if a user click on the *"Yes, delete bookmark"* button.  Therefore, you need to add to this button function a jQuery ajax function and remove your first `ajaxLink()`.

```
//in your view.phtml
<div id="dialogbox" style="display:none">Do you really want to remove this bookmark?</div>
<span style="cursor:pointer" class="btn orange delete dialog-confirm" id="1">Remove Bookmark</span>

<?php $this->jQuery()->addOnload('
$(function() {
    var id;

    $("#dialogbox").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:180,
        width:350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Yes, delete bookmark": function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/bookmark/remove/article",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: "id="+id,
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        $("."+data+"").remove();
                        if ($(".watchlist").length == 0) {
                            $(".watch").append("<p>No items watched</p>")
                        }
                    }
               });
           },
           Cancel: function() {
               $( this ).dialog( "close" );
           }
       },
    });   


    $(".delete").click(function(e) {
        id = this.id;
        console.log(id);
        $( "#dialogbox" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});
'); ?>
```

Now, if you click on **Remove Bookmark**, it displays a jQuery Dialog with two buttons: *Cancel* and *"Yes, delete bookmark"*, and once you click on yes, it calls an jQuery.ajax function and send the id to /bookmark/remove/article as a parameter.

Comment: Excellent, it works! I can not believe that I have tried for ages and now it is that easy. Thank you so much. The only think I have added is "close" behind the Yes function, otherwise the Dialog Box would stay open, even when the Bookmark gets deleted in the background. Thank you so much, don't think I would have ever found this out otherwise. Now I will just add some Message to show up, that Bookmark is deleted and find out why the Dialog Box opens already, as soon I enter the site. Thank you again !